# Convertendo um arquivo texto em XML com Python

Tags: python, xml

Imagine que eu tenha o seguinte comando:

```
echo -e "`date`\n\n`free`\n\n`vmstat`\n" >> free_vmstat_output.txt
```

o arquivo gerado (a saída do comando acima) seria (em modo TEXTO):

```
Fri Mar 31 22:19:55 -03 2017

             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:      16387080    7085084    9301996     386628     147468    3340724
-/+ buffers/cache:    3596892   12790188
Swap:     13670396          0   13670396

procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 0  0      0 9302192 147468 3340724    0    0    27    93  173   89  5  1 93  1  0
```

Como transformá-lo em XML, ou seja, preciso ler o arquivo free_vmstat_output.txt, que é a saída do comando e transformá-lo em XML?

```
Fri Mar 31 22:19:55 -03 2017 -> seria uma tag data
```

Cada elemento abaixo, seria uma tag e entraria com seus valores:

```
total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
```

Eu só comecei o seguinte trecho de código:

```
#coding:utf-8

from xml.dom.minidom import Document

doc = Document()
root = doc.createElement('InfoMemoria')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não tem mágica aí - 
é uma estrutura de dados complexa, que você quer transformar em outra estrutura complexa -

tem que ler o arquivo origem, linha a linha, separar os elementos de informação de cada linha usando as ferramentas de string do Python (`linha.strip().split("")` deve te dar uma lista com cada campo de cabeçalhos ou de dados.)

E, para cada valor desejado, você tem que criar um novo nó, no lugar certo, tudo isso para no fim ter um XML em que a informação relativa às vms serja algo como:
`<procs><r>0</r><b><0></procs><memory><swpd>0</swpd> <free>9302192</free>...</memory>`

POucas coisa sseriam mais chatas do que criar um xml como esse, dentre as quais, CONSUMIR um xml como esse.

Então - vamos voltar um passos atras: 
primeiro: se você vai suar Python para manipular os dados relativos ao sistema, por que usar uma linha de comando complexa para colar como arquivo texto a saída de comandos individuais que tem as informações que você quer?

Faça tudo em Python - incluindo a chamada aos comandos externos `free` e `vmstat` - Pra o timestam, obviament você não precisa chamar um processo externo, basta usar o datetime do Python

Segundo:  Pense no programa que vai consumir essas informações, e gere um arquivo de dados estruturado que pode ser : mais fácil de ser lido do outro lado, mais fácil de gerar com seu programa Pythn, mais legível quando for olhado, e significativamente menor!   XML perde em todos esses quesitos para quase qualquer cois - inclusive é mais verboso e menos legível do que a colagem como arquivo texto original. Para mandarum formato estruturado e facilmetne legível, você pode pensar num arquivo JSON, por exemplo, em vez de XML:

```
{"timestamp: ...
 "free": {"mem": {'total': ..., 'used': ...,  ...},
          "swap": {"total", ..., "used": ...}},
 "vmstat": ...
}
```

Ou -se voce quiser gerar vários desses para ter como monitorar o uso da máquina em algummomento ufutro, vai fazer muito mais sentido colocar tudo num banco de dados, em vez de gerar pacotinhos XML ou JSON. (ok, se o XML ou JSON podem ser para serem transmitidos para um processo remoto que faz isso).

Bom, de qualquer forma, você cria no programa Python uma função distinta para executar o comando externo, fazer o parse dos dados, e já retornar a infromaçãi estruturada  - como um dicionário Python é legal - mesmoq eu você opte por usar o XML - o dicionário será uma boa estrutura de dados intermediária.

Exemplo de uma função que chama  o "free" e faz o parse dos dados para uma estrutura de dicionário:

```
import subprocess

def get_free():
    data = subprocess.check_output("free").decode("utf-8").split("\n")
    memory = data[1].split()
    swap = data[2].split()
    result = {'memory': {'total': int(memory[1]), used: int(memory[2])},
              'swap': {'total': int(swap[1]), used: int(swap[2])}}
    return result
```

Você pode criar uma função similar para ler os dados do "vmstat", combinar os dicionários com um timestamp, e usar direto "json.dump" para ter todos os dados legíveis por máquina e prontos para serem transmitidos --- ou, cria ruma outra função que crie o seu XML baseado nos dados já estruturados.